# Genitive usage in German

Tags: grammatical-case

In the Slow German podcast #184 about German guest houses she has the sentence,

„Früher gab es die Unterscheidung beider Wörter:“

beider Wörter looks like it is in the genitive case but I do not understand why talking about a distinction between two things puts it in the genetive case. I understand the genetive case to reflect that the object of the case is possessed by something. My father´s house. Surely the distinction between the two words does not possess the two words.

Additionally I would like to understand why this is not „zwischen beider Wörter“.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, genitive isn't about possession but relation. Possesion is just the most common relation. The other is determining another noun: *our cats' mother*, *the system's failure*.

That was the two uses of the possessive case in English.

---

German uses the genitive for the same reasons as English uses its possessive. The possessive genitive is used in some unusual cases as well:

> Das ist niemandes Verdienst.

*"This is nobody's merit."*

---

The genitive use as as determiner is also more common than in English:

> Das Ende dieses Tages genießen wir bei einem gemütlichen Bier.

*"We enjoy this day's end having a placid beer."*

(English isn't my first language and I always think these are Germanisms when using the English language like that. I would rather use the preposition *of* instead.)

However, it's the same in your example:

> Früher gab es die Unterscheidung beider Wörter.

*"Earlier there was made a both's words' distinction."*

Nobody would talk or write it that way in English though. It's just a step too far.

- **In German, this is best practice.**

The alternative is using the preposition *zwischen* and the dative case, as this isn't a direction.

> Früher gab es die Unterscheidung zwischen beiden Wörtern.

This sounds a bit clumsy however.

---

In addition, a lot of German prepositions command the genitive:

> Wegen des Staus habe ich statt der Autobahn die Landstraße genommen.

*Because of the traffic jam I took the back road instead of the autobahn.*

---

For completeness, some **adjectives** also command the genitive:

> Er ist des Deutschen mächtig.

*He has command over the German language. (means: He can use it properly.)*

This is a general pattern and one of the most obscure features of the German language.  [There are lots and lots of German adjectives commanding a certain case or preposition (and case)](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/adjektiv-adverb-rektion/adjektive-die-kasus-direkt-regieren/). The genitive list is the shortest.

Most native speakers master this at about age twenty.

Answer (score 1):

For me there is a difference between

> the act of distinguishing = das Unterscheiden / die Unterscheidung (in Janka's words '*to make a distinction*')

and

> the fact of being different = difference = der Unterschied

In many cases you can transform a transitive verb together with its direct object into a noun phrase; the object then is connected as (a?) genitive:

> den Brief in 10 Minuten schreiben -> das Schreiben des Briefes dauerte 10 Minuten
>
> die Wohnung für viel Geld renovieren (lassen) -> die Renovierung der Wohnung kostete ein Vermögen

So, '*die Unterscheidung beider Wörter*' could be traced back to

> die Unterscheidung beider Wörter <- beide Wörter unterscheiden.

As Janka said, one may understand the genitive as a determiner. In the given example however it is not the same kind of determiner as in '*Peters Wagen/Peter's car*'. It must be anaphoric in the sense that the two word in question have been mentioned before.

I don't know the context, but I would prefer formulations like

> Früher wurde zwischen den Bedeutungen der beiden Wörter unterschieden.
>
> Früher unterschied man deutlicher zwischen den beiden Wörtern.
>
> Früher gebrauchte man die beiden Wörter nicht unterschiedslos.

For me the given sentence is wrong, at least it should be

> früher gab es **eine** Unterscheidung zwischen (den) beiden Wörtern

or, better

> früher machte man eine Unterscheidung zwischen (den) beiden Wörtern

or, better yet and as said before

> früher unterschied man zwischen (den) beiden Wörtern.

Comment: *Früher unterschied man die beiden Wörter deutlicher.* is also fine.